# mysql join of daily and weekly data

Tags: mysql

I try to select data from two tables and bring it together with update_date as connecting element. my problem: one table has daily data and the other weekly. If I use LEFT JOIN, it displays the data from both tables correctly - but only the weekly ones. I would like to have displayed all daily data plus the weekly ones at the respective days.
This is my code so far:

```
$query =   "SELECT * FROM `table1` 
            LEFT JOIN `table2`
            ON `table1`.`update_date` = `table2`.`update_date`
            WHERE `table1`.`market_id` = '10'
            AND `table1`.`act_contract` = 'act'
            AND `table2`.`market_id` = '10'
            ";
```

The image below shows selects from both tables to make my question easier to understand. I would like to select all entries from both tables, connected by update_date. If I have no results from table 2, the query should display the entries from update_date and sett from table1 and also comshort as NULL.

This are the tables I created:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `price_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `update_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sett` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `est_volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prior_volume` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prior_open_int` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `act_contract` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`price_ID`);
```

and the second one:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comlong` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comshort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `openinterest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
ALTER TABLE `cot-data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
```

[image: both tables]

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And be aware that `LEFT JOIN y... WHERE y=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN y...`

Comment: Sorry, Strawberry, if you don't find it reproducible. I thought, the image would illustrate my question. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Just follow the instructions provided - or don't

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a subselect.

```
SELECT *,
            (select comshort from `table2` where market_id=table1.market_id and update_date=table1.update_date)
            FROM `table1` WHERE `act_contract` = 'act' AND `market_id`= '10'
```

Answer (score -1):

My first step would be to pre-query all possible date/market combinations via the union.  NOW, you can left-join to each table individually on respective date/market.  Then you can get all the rest of the fields and apply a COALESCE() in case either table is missing a given date

```
select
      AllDates.Update_Date,
      coalesce( t1.contract_id, ' ' ) Contract_ID,
      coalesce( t1.open_id, ' ' ) open,
      coalesce( t1.high, ' ' ) high,
      coalesce( t1.low, ' ' ) low,
      coalesce( t1.close, ' ' ) close,
      coalesce( t1.sett, ' ' ) sett,
      coalesce( t1.est_volume, 0 ) est_volume,
      coalesce( t1.prior_volume, ' ' ) prior_volume,
      coalesce( t1.prior_open_int, ' ' ) prior_open_int,
      coalesce( t1.act_contract, ' ' ) act_contract,
      coalesce( t2.comLong, 0 ) comLong,
      coalesce( t2.comShort, 0 ) comShort,
      coalesce( t2.openInterest, 0 ) openInterest
   from
      ( select distinct update_date, market_id
           from table1
        union
        select distinct update_date, market_id
           from table2 ) AllDates
         LEFT JOIN table1 t1
            on AllDates.update_date = t1.update_date
            AND AllDates.market_id = t1.market_id
         LEFT JOIN table1 t2
            on AllDates.update_date = t2.update_date
            AND AllDates.market_id = t2.market_id
```